# What is the problem with my git when I upload my project to github?

Tags: reactjs, git, github

I working a react project, I am trying to push it in GitHub, I don't know where is the problem that it give such kind of an error.

The error is like:

> error: RPC failed; curl 18 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was reset, errno 10054
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> Everything up-to-date

Comment: If you are working in machine which is protected by a VPN network, you can try to disable the VPN before push.

Answer (score 0):

If your repository is large, you may need to increase the buffer size, you increase the git buffer size with the following command,

`git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

Please read the http.postBuffer parameter in the git documentation, before performing this command,
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config